# Python, returning data collected in npyscreen

Tags: python, user-interface, tui

So I'm creating a basic TUI for a script I created. The goal is to collect several variables that include paths to directories and files. What I'm not sure about is once I've created the visual aspect of it, how to get those pieces of information to interact with other parts of the code.

Below is what I have so far in terms of the visual portion (the other part is about 500 lines), and honestly I'm at a loss on how to even print any of the variables set under the class and any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import npyscreen

class PlistCreator(npyscreen.NPSApp):
    def main(self):
        screen = npyscreen.Form(name="Welcome to Nicks Playlist Creator!")
        plistName = screen.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="Playlist Name:" )
        csvPath = screen.add(npyscreen.TitleFilenameCombo, name="CSV Schedule:")
        toaPath = screen.add(npyscreen.TitleFilenameCombo, name="Path to ToA Video Folder:", use_two_lines=True)
        outputPath = screen.add(npyscreen.TitleFilenameCombo, name = "Output Folder:", use_two_lines=True)
        dateOfAir = screen.add(npyscreen.TitleDateCombo, name="Date of Air:")
        timeOfStart = screen.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="Time of Air (TC):")
        screen.edit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = PlistCreator()
    App.run()
```

Comment: Just from skimming the docs [here](http://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/application-structure.html), dsomething like `App.plistName`, `App.csvpath`, etc. work to get the values after entering? (You may need to assign them all to `self`, e.g. `self.screen = ...`)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of any form object using the dit notation.

```
plistName = screen.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="Playlist Name:" )
playlist_name = self.screen.plistName.value
```

etc. Note there are no parentheses after value. Once you have it in a variable, you can build another method in the class to handle the information.